# migrating JDK 1.8 to JDK 1.9 for Spring 3.2 x framework based on large scale enterprise application

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, ibatis

I have a spring 3.2.x application using iBATIS and tiles 3.0.x .it is running in JDK 1.8 without any issues.I am trying to migrate it to JDK 1.9.

If I migrate JDK 1.8 to JDK 1.9 What are the steps I need to follow?should I need to be upgrade spring 4.2.x jars?

Comment: JDK 9 is only supported by Spring 5. Others **might** work but you are basically on your own.

Comment: It simply will not work. Running java 8 compiled byte code on the JDK9 will not work either. I've tried.

Answer (score 0):

> should I need to be upgrade spring 4.2.x jars?

As far as i know Spring framework 5 released specially for java 9 with full compatibility. So you should use that for better results..!!